# Attribute check on nested resource with declarative authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I'm trying to add `filter_access_to` with `attribute_check: true` but my model, `Assignment`, is nested on `Project` and I want to check that the current user is assigned to the project so he/she can update the assignments (i.e. all the assignments, not just a specific one) on the project.

I have the next permission:

```
has_permissions_on :assignment do |a|
    to :read
    if_attribute :user, is { user }
end
```

And in my controller:

```
filter_access_to :all, require: :manage, context: :assignment, attribute_check: true
```

The problem is that I can't access the index page because it doesn't find the assignment's id.

My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :assignments
    belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :assignments
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific need to use `filter_access_to`, you can use `filter_resource_access` ([see docs](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/master/classes/Authorization/AuthorizationInController/ClassMethods.html#M000221)) instead and specify `:nested_in` option.

Simply change your `filer_access_to` line with the following (or similar):

```
filter_resource_access nested_in: :projects
```

If you **really** want to continue using `filter_access_to`, then you need to create an instance of Assignment associated with Project and assign it to `@assignment` instance variable in a `before_filter`. This is what Declarative Authorization does under the hood when you use `filter_resource_access`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that did the trick for me:

```
before_filter :set_assignment
    filter_access_to [:index,:create,:destroy], require: :manage, context: :assignment, attribute_check: true
....
def set_assignment
  @project ||= Project.find(params[:project_id])
  p = {project_id: @project.id}.merge(params[:assignment] || {})
  @assignment ||= (params[:id] ? Assignment.find(params[:id]) : Assignment.new(p))
end
```

No idea why `filter_resource_access :nested_in => :project` didn't work. It worked for `index` but it didn't for `create` and `destroy`.